# Grub Rescue Error:no such partition not allowing to boot from CD/USB

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I have Lenovo G570.I had win8 and Ubuntu 12.04 for dual booting. But accidentally I have deleted Ubuntu partition, now it's showing grub rescue error: `no such partition error.`
I have bootable PD.I am trying to boot from PD.but whenever I switch on my laptop and press <kbd>F2</kbd>( BIOS key for Lenovo) or <kbd>F12</kbd>(Boot Sequence),it is doing nothing, only showing Grub rescue.
What to do. I have tried all keys like <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> but it does nothing.

I have deleted the Ubuntu partition. and now I want to install Ubuntu again.I have bootable PD and also have a CD. My problem is that my system is not booting from that PD/CD. What should I do in this case.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? Did you "remove" (in the sense of making the partition free, unallocated space) the partition, or did you format the partition? Also, erasing a partition will not modify your bios sequence. Most laptops are set to boot from CD. Are you able to boot a Linux live disc like Ubuntu? That would be able to tell you more information about partitions and where they are located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any key combination to activate F2 or F12 in Lenovo, confirm that. Issues like these don't usually happen.

And if you remove Hard Disk, you may be able to boot from USB but it can't be permanent solution. Because to fix boot error the MBR should be installed in Hard Disk.